# Which scale(s) can I use?

Tags: chord-progressions, modal

I've just come back from my jazz workshop and the lines I played over a G7 C7 G7 D7#9 Eb7#9 D7#9b13 G7 progression were ok, -ish. When asked, our teacher told me to try dorian scales, over mixolydian and altered chords. What is your angle on this?

Comment: All Blues? If so, it helps a lot to listen to the soloists on that recording.

Comment: You spotted it right away of course. I didn't know if it was alright to actually name the tune. You guys are so strict. But I suppose you have to. I agree with you: listen listen, listen...but I'm just an amateur and although I try to train my ear as best I can, I'd love to have some tips about that tune.  I have fun on swing progressions but blues progressions are a big deal for me. I'm European, you see.  I played bebop C all over the progression but wasn't really happy about it, obviously. I have good phrasing and a good sense of time but I want to improve.

Comment: @user45784, a full transcription of Coltrane's solo can be found [on page 60 of this document](http://jeffweissmusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/John-Coltrane-Artist-Transcriptions.pdf).

Comment: @jdjazz, Thanks. I think I'll try to figure out which scales he plays throughout and when. Miles Davis' solo is easier to follow on the guitar but Trane's is a hard nut to crack. I appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Common scales that "fit" the 7th chord include:

- Myxolydian (b7)
- Major pentatonic (1, 2, 3, 5, 6)
- Bebop (b7, natural 7)
- Lydian dominant (#4, b7)
- Whole tone
- Diminished (half, then whole steps)
- Diminished whole tone (b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7 - most common on "#9b13" chords)

---

If you haven't seen [this video from the "Jazz Tutorials" channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ro2dVvwzKNs), I would strongly suggest it. The Lydian Dominant scale emerges from the teacher's "chord tones + whole step" philosophy.

Comment: You can find these (and more!) scales in Jamey Aebersold's *Scale Syllabus*: http://jazzbooks.com/mm5/download/FREE-scale-syllabus.pdf

Comment: Might be worth adding the relative Dorian for a sus sound. For example, over G7, play D dorian.

Comment: Indeed. The scale syllabus uses a separate notation (G7 sus 4, or D-/G), so maybe I'll just relegate this info to the comments!

Comment: Do you consider a change from G7 to G7sus4 to be in a different category from G7 → G7#11 or G7 → G7alt? Don't they all use separate notations?

Comment: I don't know of a consistent way to measure how different one chord symbol (or chord) is from the next, but "not having a 3rd" seems like a big enough distinction.

Comment: Every single option (G7sus, G7alt, G7#11) changes the harmony. But every single option (G7sus, G7alt, G7#11) also preserves the underlying dominant 7th harmony. The G7sus chord doesn't change the harmony--it's still a dominant 7th chord. Playing the major 3rd over a G7sus isn't uncommon by any means (the suspension-resolution makes a nice sound). Further to this point, you can sometimes find Keith Jarrett voicing sus chords with a major third on the top of the chord as part of an upper structure.

Comment: Given (a) how common a sus sound is over extended improvisation on a dom7 chord, (b) the use of sus chords & lines in the original recording of All Blues (particularly over the IV7 chord), (c) the nature of this question (asking about scales rather than chords), and (d) the mention of dorian in the original post, I think it's worth including. (I really like this post overall and I gave it a +1 when making the original comment.)

Answer (score 2):

It's important to realize that not every scale that can theoretically be played over a dominant seventh chord is also a good choice in a specific musical context. In the case of the given progression the following scales are used in practice:

```
G7     G mixolydian
C7     C mixolydian
D7#9   D half-whole, D altered, D (minor) blues
Eb7#9  Eb half-whole, Eb altered, Eb (minor) blues
```

Note that there's not a lot of time to play scales over the D7#9 and the Eb7#9 chords, so what people usually do is play (incomplete) arpeggios. As I've mentioned in a comment, you can learn a lot by analyzing the solos played by the greats. As an example, try to play an Fm7 arpeggio over D7#9, and a Gbm7 arpeggio over Eb7#9. In this way you'll play the 7, b9, #9, and the #11 of the respective chord.

It's also helpful to analyze the melody, and use it in your improvisations. The first thing that one notices it that over D7#9 the perfect fifth (A) as well as the #5 (b13) are used. Over Eb7#9 it's also the perfect fifth, not an altered fifth, that is used. This would imply the half-whole scale rather than the altered scale over these two chords. Another suitable choice matching the note choice of the melody over these two chords is the (minor) blues scale, which will give you the 5, 7, and #9.

Comment: This is very interesting: you use arpeggios from the II chord of the melodic minor scale from which the alt. chord is derived, right? Yet the quality should be half-diminished... so you actually substitute the Fmb5 for Fm7.

Comment: @user45784: The ii chord of melodic minor is a minor 7 chord, not a half-diminished chord (the half-diminished would occur in harmonic and natural minor).

Comment: you're right. Got it mixed up because II chords in minor are generally half-diminished. It's a Xsusb9 chord. Thx

Comment: +1 Nice overview. Might be worth mentioning the ways one can stretch the song over the I7 and IV7 chords as that seems to be what the instructor was suggesting. @user45784, if you listen to Coltrane's solo on All Blues, you can hear the [whole tone scale](https://youtu.be/uRBgy43gCoQ?t=406) at 6:48, the [lydian dominant](https://youtu.be/uRBgy43gCoQ?t=446) scale at 7:30, [who knows](https://youtu.be/uRBgy43gCoQ?t=462) at 7:43, a [relative minor](https://youtu.be/uRBgy43gCoQ?t=465) lick at 7:46, and an [altered scale](https://youtu.be/uRBgy43gCoQ?t=471) at 7:51 and 7:55.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really asking the right question! It's taking a narrow, inward-looking, mechanical approach to a wide topic - how to play good jazz.

It's often a good idea to find a song using the chord sequence and see what the original melody was.  That may well be the BEST thing to play over that sequence.  And I bet is isn't just scales.

Comment: Is this an answer? The question is "what scales can I use?" It seems like you're answering a different question, "how do I learn to improvise over these changes?"

Comment: @jdjazz - Right now, the question reads: _When asked, our teacher told me to try dorian scales, over mixolydian and altered chords. What is your angle on this?_  So IMO this is a perfectly valid answer: The angle is "Find a tune that uses those changes, hear the melody line and listen to what the soloists do with it." I upvoted this answer. I think it's a very good "angle".

Comment: @Stinkfoot, the question is in the title: "which scale(s) can I use?" The asker offers three example scales. He asks what folks think about *the three example scales* in the context of a question *about scales*. I agree that "listen to the tune" is useful advice, but it's not an answer to this question which is very narrowly focused on scales. I don't think the usefulness supersedes the lack of answer to the actual question.

Comment: He wants to play good jazz.  Let's not find reasons to stop us suggesting how.

Comment: @jdjazz  - I agree here with Laurence Payne in his comment. I think you are splitting straws in your criticism, especially since the question is much more clearly explained in the body than the title, which is a very brief - and based on the follow-up, not an entirely accurate -
 encapsulation of the content. This isn't an patent application. :)

Comment: @LaurencePayne, oftentimes in my learning a specific question will arise. To continue progressing, the most helpful thing is often a specific answer. Other general advice can be helpful, but the primary reason for asking a question to get an answer. I think you've left the question unanswered.

Comment: @Stinkfoot, the title could not be clearer: he plainly asks what scales can be used. The body could not be clearer: he suggests one possible answer to his own question, listing three scales. Then he asks what people think about the three proposed scales. There is no ambiguity. To assert that the asker is mistaken or wrong seems plainly false.

Comment: Ok guys! I didn't want to trigger Major (in which key? I  don't know) mayhem here. I'll go for a BB King box and call it a day ! ;))

Comment: Sometimes the best answer can be 'You're not really asking the right question!'.   When someone asks for a mechanical solution to an artistic question, they deserve guidance.

Comment: @LaurencePayne, I completely agree with you, and I think that's an excellent example of why the comment feature is so useful. I would upvote this if it were a comment. (I have found that a combination of knowledge about scales + listening to recordings to be the most helpful.)

Comment: Go on then!  I've added to my answer.